# Empty response using Speech-to-Text API on WAV file

Tags: python, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I have a WAV file generated from a stream using WebRTC. The sample demo [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text) is able to transcribe it with results but my code is failing to do so as I'm getting an empty response. Here's my config:

```
​audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(content=content)

config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.OGG_OPUS,
    sample_rate_hertz=48000,
    language_code="es-US",
    audio_channel_count=2,
    enable_separate_recognition_per_channel=True,
    use_enhanced=True,
    model="command_and_search"
)
```

[Download audio](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iyeunt0c1xuuubd/hola.wav?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your file using the configuration you provided and I get blank results as well. I'm not sure what code or version of the API on the backend of [Try it demo](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text) uses that makes your audio file work seamlessly. But what I did as a workaround is I converted your file to FLAC and it worked.

To convert the file I used FFMPEG. You can use any audio converter tool that you have as long as it properly converts it to FLAC. See command:

```
ffmpeg -i hola.wav hola.flac
```

Using the converted file I changed the audio encoding in the config to flac and it worked fine. See code below:

```
def transcribe_file(speech_file):
    from google.cloud import speech
    import io

    client = speech.SpeechClient()

    with io.open(speech_file, "rb") as audio_file:
        content = audio_file.read()

    audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(content=content)
    config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC,
        sample_rate_hertz=48000,
        audio_channel_count=2,
        language_code="en-US",
        model="command_and_search"
    )

    response = client.recognize(config=config, audio=audio)
    print(response)

    for result in response.results:
        print(u"Transcript: {}".format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))

transcribe_file("./hola.flac")
```

Output:

[image]

Also for reference, when empty result is encountered and you have tried to [optimize the audio (split into mono)](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/optimizing-audio-files-for-speech-to-text#optimizing_audio_files_for_analysis) and still fails. Try converting the file to FLAC as suggested by [troubleshooting docs](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/troubleshooting#returns_an_empty_response).

Comment: Thank you! That is correct, it works converting to FLAC, although, I have only confirmed the conversion output works only using the type of WAV file that I'm generating. Still, problem solved :)